# SpringBoot AMPQ on Docker cannot always connect to the queue

Tags: java, docker, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I have a SpringBoot app and I want to conncct to rabbit mq and read some messages. However I do have an issue that when I deploy the app, sometimes it connects to rabbit instantly and starts working but more often It only tries to connect and tries and finally I recive timeout exception just like that:

```
2018-10-17 09:03:54.460 ERROR 15 --- [ main] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Consumer failed to start in 60000 milliseconds; does the task executor have enough threads to support the container concurrency?
```

I use AWS ECS so my app is running in docker container. Could it be related ?

Here is my configuration where all those environment variables are valid

```
spring.rabbitmq.host=${RABBIT_HOST}
spring.rabbitmq.port=${RABBIT_PORT}
spring.rabbitmq.username=${RABBIT_USERNAME}
spring.rabbitmq.password=${RABBIT_PASSWORD}
spring.rabbitmq.virtualHost=${RABBIT_HOST}
rabbitmq.queues=myQueue
```

And my code

```
@Component
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
final class ListingMessageListener {

    private final BackOfficeService backOfficeService;

    @RabbitListener(queues = "${rabbitmq.queues}")
    public void receiveMessage(final ListingMessage listingMessage) {
        final String listingId = listingMessage.getMessage().getListingId();
        log.info("Received listingId= {}", listingId);            
Optional.ofNullable(backOfficeService.getOfferById(Long.valueOf(listingId))).ifPresent(offer -> log.info(offer.getName()));

    }
}
```

Comment: I'm also facing this issue. Any solution?

Comment: @Krishnanunni, did you get a solution to your issue?